# How to update tableau extensions API graph after toggling dashboard filter?

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am using Tableau to create a dashboard. I needed the power of D3 in my dashboard, and so I created a Tableau Extension that creates the viz. Here's the skeleton of the JS that uses the Tableau Extensions API functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log('were in again'); 
  tableau.extensions.initializeAsync().then(function () {

    // To get dataSource info, first get the dashboard.
    const dashboard = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard;
    const worksheets = dashboard.worksheets;

    let underlyingDataFetchPromises = [];
    let dataObjects = {};
    let worksheetNames = [];

    // Save Promises to Array + Add Event Listeners
    dashboard.worksheets.forEach(worksheet => {
      worksheetNames.push(worksheet.name);
      underlyingDataFetchPromises.push(worksheet.getUnderlyingDataAsync());

      // add event listener too...
      worksheet.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.FilterChanged, (filterEvent) => {
        clearChart();
        drawChart(dataObjects.dataA, dataObjects.dataB);
      });
    });

    // Maps dataSource id to dataSource so we can keep track of unique dataSources.
    Promise.all(underlyingDataFetchPromises).then(fetchedData => {

      // loop over the 2 fetchedData arrays [(1) dataA, (2) dataB]
      fetchedData.forEach((dataTable, i) => {
        let data = dataTable.data;
        let columns = dataTable.columns;
        let formattedData = formatData(data, columns);
        dataObjects[worksheetNames[i]] = formattedData;
      });

      // currently requires worksheets named "dataA" and "dataB"... not flexible atm
      drawChart(dataObjects.dataA, dataObjects.dataB);
    });

  }, function (err) {
    // Something went wrong in initialization.
    console.log('Error while Initializing: ' + err.toString());
  }); 
});
```

`cleanData()` and `drawChart()` are functions I wrote myself that draw the D3 visualizations, these are working. My event handler "works" a bit, in the sense that it is properly triggered when a fitler in the dashboard is changed.

**However**, my problem is that, when `drawChart()` is called from within the eventListener, my chart is drawn with **the same data**, not the new data resulting from the filter being toggled. I understand inherently why this is the case - the eventListener is not refetching data, only redrawing the chart.

My question is then, how do I re-fetch new data to re-draw my viz correctly after the filters are toggled? And also, is there a function that will return to me the filter names + values, that I can use to improve the functionality of my extension? It would be good to have all of the dashboard filters + values in JS to use in this code.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code refreshes the data source "ABC" and reloads the workbook-

```
/**
 * This function is designed to refresh a specific Tableau data source named "ABC"
 * within a Tableau dashboard extension. It initializes the extension, finds all
 * data sources, and refreshes the target data source.
 */
function refreshMySql() {
  tableau.extensions.initializeAsync().then(() => {
    // Fetch data sources from each worksheet and consolidate them.
    const dashboard = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard;
    let dataSourceFetchPromises = dashboard.worksheets.map(worksheet => worksheet.getDataSourcesAsync());
    let dashboardDataSources = {};

    Promise.all(dataSourceFetchPromises).then(fetchResults => {
      fetchResults.forEach(dataSourcesForWorksheet => {
        dataSourcesForWorksheet.forEach(dataSource => {
          // Process each data source only once.
          if (!dashboardDataSources[dataSource.id]) {
            dashboardDataSources[dataSource.id] = dataSource;

            // Check if the data source name matches "ABC" and refresh it.
            if (dataSource.name === "ABC") {
              refreshDataSource(dataSource);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('Error while fetching data sources: ' + err.toString());
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('Error while initializing Tableau Extensions API: ' + err.toString());
  });
}

/**
 * Refreshes the given data source.
 * @param {object} dataSource - The data source to be refreshed.
 */
function refreshDataSource(dataSource) {
  dataSource.refreshAsync().then(() => {
    console.log(`${dataSource.name}: Refreshed Successfully`);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(`Error refreshing data source ${dataSource.name}: ` + err.toString());
  });
}

// Execute the refresh function when the document is ready.
$(document).ready(refreshMySql);
```

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/tableau/extensions-api/blob/master/Samples-Typescript/DataSources/datasources.ts)

[Tableau Writeback Source](https://tableaufans.com/extension-api/tableau-extension-api-write-back-source-code/)